# Pandas: Any cleaner way to merge multiple time

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

reference_df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [ 1,  1,  1,  1, 2,  2,  2,  2,
                                     3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                   'time' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,
                             1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'value_initial'  : [1, 2, 2, 3,
                                2, 3, 3, 3,
                                1, 1, 1, 1,
                                2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'value_final'  : [5, 5, 5, 5,
                                4, 4, 4, 4,
                                3, 3, 3, 3,
                                4, 4, 4, 4]})


df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [5,6],
                   'time': [3, 4],
                   'value_present': [11, 12]})


df['id_past_1'] = df['id'] - 1
df['id_past_2'] = df['id'] - 2
df['id_past_3'] = df['id'] - 3


df = df.merge(reference_df, left_on=['id_past_1', 'time'], right_on=['id', 'time'], how='left')
df.drop('id_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'value_initial': 'value_initial_1', 'value_final': 'value_final_1', 'id_x':'id'}, inplace=True)

df = df.merge(reference_df, left_on=['id_past_2', 'time'], right_on=['id', 'time'], how='left')
df.drop('id_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'value_initial': 'value_initial_2', 'value_final': 'value_final_2', 'id_x':'id'}, inplace=True)

df = df.merge(reference_df, left_on=['id_past_3', 'time'], right_on=['id', 'time'], how='left')
df.drop('id_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'value_initial': 'value_initial_3', 'value_final': 'value_final_3', 'id_x':'id'}, inplace=True)
```

I need to update/merge the df above using reference_df. Above snipped work fine as far as computation is concerned. The concern is multiple drop and rename operation that is required. Is this the right pandas practice or can this be done any better?

Comment: you can use simple for loop to avoid this much code redundancy

Comment: Any other way apart from loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [5,6],
                   'time': [3, 4],
                   'value_present': [11, 12]})

for i in range(1,4):
    df[f"id_past_{i}"] = df['id'] - i
    df = df.merge(reference_df, left_on=[f'id_past_{i}', 'time'], right_on=['id', 'time'], how='left', suffixes=(None, '_y'))
    df.drop('id_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.rename(columns={'value_initial': f'value_initial_{i}', 'value_final': f'value_final_{i}'}, inplace=True)
```